# Create javascript array using xml attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, parsing, filereader

Given this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GRAPHVS>
    <BASICS>
        <numbers name="model.XML" type="Euclidean/symmetric/mixed" number_of_vertices="2" number_of_links="1" Coordinate_System="Euclidean/UTM/Polar" date_creation="23/06/2017" hour_creation="12:16:24"/>
    </BASICS>
    <VERTICES>
        <node id="1" coordx="100.02346" coordy="80.00101" coordz="21.10201" group="1" r="1" g="0" b="0" node_type="simple"/>
        <node id="2" coordx="120.12346" coordy="89.02112" coordz="26.20111" group="2" r="1" g="0" b="0" node_type="origin"/>
        <node id="3" coordx="125.12346" coordy="80.02112" coordz="22.20111" group="2" r="1" g="0" b="0" node_type="destination"/>
        <node id="4" coordx="120.12786" coordy="79.17842" coordz="19.27811" group="3" r="0" g="0" b="1" node_type="center"/>
    </VERTICES>
    <LINKS>
        <link origin="1" destination="2" cost="177" edge="1" linklabel="0" required="1" Cost="177" group="1" r="" g="" b="" />
    </LINKS>
</GRAPHVS>
```

Using the [FileReader](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) I want to get only a few attributes from this file, like `id`, `coordx`, `coordy`, `coordz`, `r`, `g` and `b`, to push them into a 2D Array like this:

```
var verticesArray = [
    [1, 100.02346, 80.00101, 21.10201, 1, 0, 0],
    [2, 120.12346, 89.02112, 26.20111, 1, 0, 0],
    [3, 125.12346, 80.02112, 22.20111, 1, 0, 0],
    [4, 120.12786, 79.17842, 19.27811, 0, 0, 1]
];
```

So far I've only parsed the file, but I'm having trouble on how to get exactly those attributes into the array, since I'm kinda new with JS

```
function readXML(evt) {
    var xmlFile = evt.target.files;
    var verticesArray = [];
    if (xmlFile){
        var xmlReader = new FileReader();
        xmlReader.onload = function() {
            var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");
            console.log(parsed);
        };
        xmlReader.readAsText(xmlFile[0]);
    } else {
        alert("Failed");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts oh how can I manage that out?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to query all the nodes using the querySelector API, and get the desired attributes from this elements:

```js
/* This part is just to be able to run this snippet, in your case this string is coming from the file */
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GRAPHVS>
    <BASICS>
        <numbers name="model.XML" type="Euclidean/symmetric/mixed" number_of_vertices="2" number_of_links="1" Coordinate_System="Euclidean/UTM/Polar" date_creation="23/06/2017" hour_creation="12:16:24"/>
    </BASICS>
    <VERTICES>
        <node id="1" coordx="100.02346" coordy="80.00101" coordz="21.10201" group="1" r="1" g="0" b="0" node_type="simple"/>
        <node id="2" coordx="120.12346" coordy="89.02112" coordz="26.20111" group="2" r="1" g="0" b="0" node_type="origin"/>
        <node id="3" coordx="125.12346" coordy="80.02112" coordz="22.20111" group="2" r="1" g="0" b="0" node_type="destination"/>
        <node id="4" coordx="120.12786" coordy="79.17842" coordz="19.27811" group="3" r="0" g="0" b="1" node_type="center"/>
    </VERTICES>
    <LINKS>
        <link origin="1" destination="2" cost="177" edge="1" linklabel="0" required="1" Cost="177" group="1" r="" g="" b="" />
    </LINKS>
</GRAPHVS>
`;

const xmlEl = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
const nodes = [...xmlEl.querySelectorAll("node")];
const columns = ["id", "coordx", "coordy", "r", "g", "b"];

const verticesArray = nodes.map(n => columns.map(col => n.getAttribute(col)));

console.log(verticesArray)
```

I'm using some ES2015 features as "const, "arrow functions" and the "spread operator (the tree dots)", but if you're using just ES5 you can just change it for "var"s, "function(){ }"s and the "Array slice" respectively:

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(xmlEl.querySelectorAll("node"))
```

Comment: Ok, so if I'm right the arrow function should be something like this:
`verticesArray = nodes.map(function (n){
 columns.map(function (col){
  return n.getAttribute(col);
 })
})`

but this is giving me an array of undefined values

Comment: In the first function you should return the "columns.map" result:

```verticesArray = nodes.map(function (n){ return columns.map(function (col){ return n.getAttribute(col);```